# Executing multiple queries and then finding matches between returned values

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on creating an "advanced search" for this directory I'm working on. Right now you can only search by keyword, but I have about four drop-downs that I'd like to use for filtering down the entries. Each drop-down will basically match up with a different table in the database, the entryID being the common element shared among all of the drop-downs.

My problem is, I'm confident I can come up with the right query for each drop-down, but putting them all together so that an entry will match attributes from either one drop-down, or multiple drop-downs, I'm not sure exactly how to do this.

I think my best plan of action would be to run each query individually, depending on which drop-downs were altered, and then find the matches between the returned rows. Is this possible with MySQL, and if so, how would I go about doing this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It would be more efficient to combine all of the search criteria into one query. Please post the code for your html form and your current queries and so we can make further suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats not the right way

Lets say you have three tables each with one column

```
TABLE1 (column1)
TABLE2 (column2)
TABLE3 (column3)
```

if you want to run query that finds row with all three values in column1,2,3 matched you have to do smth like this

```
SELECT * from table1,table2,table3 WHERE column1=X AND column2=Y AND column3=Z;
```

bassically what we do here is joining all tables together.You can imagine it like glueing them together next to each other. Then you are looking for rows that match your criteria